# App store guidelines - Can I take users phone contacts and store them on a web server?

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval

I've checked the offical apply guidelines for app reviews but could get an answer.  I'm developing an app that will take users phone contacts and store them on my server.  These contacts will then be visible to certain other app users.  Assuming that I alert the users that their contacts are being stored and will be visible to some other users, will this be a problem?  Are apple likely to reject this?

Comment: you have to mention this in your privacy policy. probably you should be avoid to share user's personal info with others.

Comment: It should be OK, just be very clear about what you're doing in the app. You can use the `NSContactsUsageDescription` key for your Info.plist to add an extra message, so that users can decide at the point of access request whether or not to allow it.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Most Helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no objection for the same from apple.
the main thing that apple may prompt about is the app user should be aware of the fact that your app will do something like this (storing user's contacts on server)
there are some popular apps that are already doing the same like TrueCaller but the app user knows that this is going to happen if he uses the app so no issues...!
I hope this helps.